# Nestjs Custom Pipe Problem in Get controllers

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to write a **Custom Pipe** in **Nestjs** to manipulate the data I receive from user in request. In Http methods that have **Body**, like **Post** I can easily get request data. But the problem appears in **Get** requests. In Get requests "value" is always `{}`.

What I try to do is to filter list data by get filter data from **Query** and for some query parameters change and pass them to controller in **regex** form of them using mongoose.

Here is my simple pipe:

```
import { ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

const targetKeys = ['name', 'username', 'email'];

@Injectable()
export class FilterStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { type, data, metatype } = metadata;

    if (type != 'query') return value;

    if (value) {
      for (let key in value) {
        if(targetKeys.includes(key)) value[key] = {$regex: /`${key}`/, $options: 'i'}
      }
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

Worth meantioning that this Pipe is defined globally in ***main.ts*** file:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({whitelist: true}),
    new FilterStringPipe(),
  )
```

so for example when I request to this @Get() api with Postman:

[{{baseUrl}}/api/v1/users/admin/list?roles=ADMIN&username=super](https://%7B%7BbaseUrl%7D%7D/api/v1/users/admin/list?roles=ADMIN&username=super)

"value" is an empty object. But Nestjs documentation does not points to any restriction in data of @Get endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Add context:

`import { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';`
and

```
 export class FilterStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata, context: ExecutionContext) {
        const { type, data, metatype } = metadata;
    
        if (type != 'query') return value;
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const value = request.query;
    
        if (value) {
          for (let key in value) {
            if (targetKeys.includes(key)) {
              value[key] = { $regex: new RegExp(value[key], 'i') };
            }
          }
        }
    
        return value;
```

Comment: transform method does not accept this parameter